# PHP how get new array from two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have w1[6][9]

```
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
for($j=0;$j<9;$j++){
    $key=rand(0,8);
    $w1[$i][$j]=$mas[$key];
}
}
```

And I have s1[6];

```
$s1=[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1];
```

How can I a[0..5] , where every element is a+=w1[i][j]*s[j] ? 
For example: a1=0.1*1+0.2*0+0.3*1+ ...+0.5*1+0.4*0+0.2*1

Comment: This questin and its title are very poorly written / formatted.  If KrisRoofe has sufficiently answered your question please award the green tick to his answer.  Either way, you should edit this question to improve clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iterate the array to do the multiply like this:

```
$o = [];
foreach($w1 as $arr)
{
  $sum = 0;
  foreach($arr as $k => $v)
  {
      $sum += $v * $s1[$k];
  }
  $o[] = $sum;
}
dd($o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this php function: http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php

It merges arrays in to one array.